# Blender not rendering full image?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

Here's what the render looks like:
[image: render]

Here's my scene:
[image: scene in viewport]

This is done in blender internal renderer.

Why is it only rendering that bit in a circle?

**[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0aoaav4hv436tsf/smoke%2Bfire.blend?dl=0)**

Comment: this looks really big, check the clipping in camera setting (and focal)

Comment: @Bithur just put it up a ton. I will say what happens when it's done rendering

Comment: @Bithur same result as above. Still not getting the full render

Comment: this perfect circle shape... but not so distorted. can you upload blend?

Comment: any compositing? or hidden objects?

Comment: @Bithur I added the .blend

Comment: mist too high in world settings!

Comment: @Bithur what do I need to change the settings to?

Comment: Never mind I just turned it off. Thanks for your help! I'm just going to close this question now.

Comment: start at 30 or something like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mist settings are bad. To see it, select the camera and check "mist"
[image]

You can change this in world settings
[image]